# Match the pattern and print next line

Tags: python, pattern-matching, generator, regex-lookarounds

I have a text file that contains certain rules. Here is format for it:

```
:SchoolName (rule_1)
)
:xyz (true)
:abc_efg (
    : xxyyzz-x1y1-z1z2-z3z4
)
```

1. I want to match for ':abc_efg' and get line after the match i.e.
   ': xxyyzz-x1y1-z1z2-z3z4'
2. Everytime there is a new file it would look for ':abc_efg' and get corresponding line after the match

So far I have tried

```
with open('G:\CM\Python Exercises\Project_F\abc.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    list1=text.strip('\n\t').split(':')
    print list1
    for line in list1:
        if ':abc_efg' in list1:
            print line
            print '\n'.join(list1[i+1])
```

print list1 shows

```
[':abc_efg (\n\t\t\t', ': xxyyzz-x1y1-z1z2-z3z4 \n\t\t)\n\t\t']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use f.readline() to read a file line by line.

It makes it easy to get the next line when there is a match.

```
with open('abc.txt') as f:
    a = ' '
    while(a):
        a = f.readline()
        l = a.find(':abc_efg') #Gives a non-negative value when there is a match
        if ( l >= 0 ):
            print f.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex, firstly it is **efficient** and second, the `str` methods get out of control if used for heavy parsing.

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r":(?P<x>.+?)\s\(\s+:\s(?P<y>.+?)\s\)")
with open(somefile) as fr:
    match = pat.search(fr.read())
    print(match.groupdict())


Out[111]: {'x': 'abc_efg', 'y': 'xxyyzz-x1y1-z1z2-z3z4'}
```

Break the regex into multiple lines to see it clearly.